# Show that $|{|2\overline{z}+5 |(\sqrt2 - i)} | = \sqrt3 |2z+5|$, where z is a complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that $|{|2\overline{z}+5 |(\sqrt2 - i)} | = \sqrt3 |2z+5|$, where z is a complex number.

And $\overline{z}$ is complex conjugate of $z$.

And $i$ is iota.

I'm proceeding by considering $z=x+iy$

But I just get stuck at different results approaching different ways. 
Please help.

Comment: |ab|= |a||b|, a,b complex.LHS: $√3|2\overline{z}+5|$.Then $|a|=|\overline{a}|$.Helps?

Comment: @PeterSzilas I didn't understand, how can you bring LHS as $\sqrt3|2\overline{z}+5|$ . I mean how did you proceed with the LHS to get that!?

Comment: Kaustuv.$|√2-i|=\sqrt{(√2)^2+i^2}=\sqrt{4-1} =√3.$Ok?

Comment: @PeterSzilas yes. I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Kaustuv.Welcome:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LHS is $||2\overline{z}+5|\cdot(\sqrt2 - i)|$; and $a=|2\overline{z}+5| \geq 0$. Then
$$||2\overline{z}+5|\cdot(\sqrt2 - i)|=|a\cdot(\sqrt2 - i)|=|a|\cdot|\sqrt2 - i|\\=\sqrt3 \cdot a=\sqrt3 \cdot |2\overline{z}+5|=\sqrt3 \cdot |\overline{2z+5}|$$

Comment: I think this is a silly question but how is $|\sqrt2-i| = \sqrt3$

Comment: $|a+ib| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, where $z = a+ib$. In this case, $a = \sqrt2,\ b = -1$

Comment: haha, damn. I didn't even think like that! Thankyou very much!!